# Execute an Impala query and get query time

Tags: impala

I want to be able to execute a number of Impala queries and return the time it took for each query to execute. Using the Impala shell, I can do this with the following command:

```
impl -q "select count(*) from database.table;"
```

This gives me the output

```
Using service name 'impala'
SSL is enabled. Impala server certificates will NOT be verified (set --ca_cert to change)
Connected to *****.************:21000
Server version: impalad version 2.6.0-cdh5.8.3 RELEASE (build c644f476b774db9db87a619628f7a6ecc5f843e0)
Query: select count(*) from database.table
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 1130976  |
+----------+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.86s
```

I want to be able to fetch that last line and extract the time. It doesn't really matter how, which is why I haven't tagged a language. I have tried using grep like this:

```
impl -q "select count(*) from database.table" | grep -Po "\d+\.\d+"
```

But that does nothing but remove the table. Putting the query in a python script and using subprocess couldn't find `impl` as a command, and same for scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird thing is that `impala-shell` dumps those messages to stderr rather than to stdout, so to fetch the last line, you would have to append a `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout

```
impala-shell -q "query string" 2>&1 | grep -Po "\d+\.\d+(?=s)"
```

Notice that a positive lookahead `(?=s)` is probably required to avoid capturing version numbers

Comment: Good call on `stderr`! Fixed the problem immediately. Do you know if there's a way to do this from a scripting language (other than bash)? Calling from Python still yields an error

Comment: @bendl What kind of error message do you get? I had a similar issue previously of impala-shell not supporting Python 3

Comment: It was that `impl` wasn't a command... I used `which impl` from command line to find what `impl` was short for and it worked